# Custom Helpers in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, helper

I am trying to create a custom helper in Laravel 5.6

My Helpers path is app\Helpers\ReadExcel.php

Following is my Helper File:

```php
<?php
    namespace App\Helpers;

    class ReadExcel{

        public static function index($id){
            echo $id;
        }
    }

?>
```

My Helper's service provider is as follows

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ReadExcelServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        require_once app_path() . '/Helpers/ReadExcel.php';
    }
}
```

Following changes are made in `config\app.php`
In providers array:

```php
App\Providers\ReadExcelServiceProvider::class,
In aliases array:
'ReadExcel' => App\Helpers\ReadExcel::class,
```

I am trying to use the helper in my controller method as follows:

```php
use ReadExcel;


public function read(){
    ReadExcel::index(3);
}
```

I get the Error as follows:

> Class 'ReadExcel' not found

Kindly help me with this. I am not sure where is the mistake.

Comment: You don't need a service provider to register your helper class. instead that simply add an alias in `config/app.php` like `'ReadExcel' => 'App\Helpers\ReadExcel',`

Comment: I have tried this one in my own setup and it works. Try to clear the config cache(By running 'Php artisan config:clear' command). That may help you.

Comment: I am not sure, but try importing the class in your controller. Or, use full path of the class in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Helpers defines simple functions like `str_slug('Slug Name')` not a Class. Once you defines all your simple functions, you can add it in `composer.json` to register instead of using `ServiceProvider`.

You can register your Helper functions in the `autoload` section of `composer.json` file like below,

```
"autoload": {
  "files": [
    "app/Helpers/ReadExcel.php"
  ],
  ...
}
```